# Как сделать чтобы при клике по элементу балуна (в кластере аккордеон) не отображался подблок с подробностями (clusterBalloonItemContentLayout)?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
var mapCenter = [55.755381, 37.619044],
map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
center: mapCenter,
zoom: 9,
controls: []
});
// Создаем собственный макет с информацией о выбранном геообъекте.
var customItemContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
// Флаг "raw" означает, что данные вставляют "как есть" без экранирования html.
'Какое свойство задать, чтобы при клике по метке эта область вообще не отображалась?'
);
var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
// Устанавливаем стандартный макет балуна кластера "Карусель".
clusterBalloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonAccordion',
// Устанавливаем собственный макет.
clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: customItemContentLayout,
// Устанавливаем режим открытия балуна. 
// В данном примере балун никогда не будет открываться в режиме панели.
clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity,
// Устанавливаем размеры макета контента балуна (в пикселях).
clusterBalloonContentLayoutWidth: 200,
clusterBalloonContentLayoutHeight: 130,
// Устанавливаем максимальное количество элементов в нижней панели на одной странице
clusterBalloonPagerSize: 5
// Настройка внешего вида нижней панели.
// Режим marker рекомендуется использовать с небольшим количеством элементов.
// clusterBalloonPagerType: 'marker',
// Можно отключить зацикливание списка при навигации при помощи боковых стрелок.
// clusterBalloonCycling: false,
// Можно отключить отображение меню навигации.
// clusterBalloonPagerVisible: false
});
// Заполняем кластер геообъектами со случайными позициями.
var placemarks = [];
for (var i = 0, l = 100; i < l; i++) {
var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(getRandomPosition(), {
// Устаналиваем данные, которые будут отображаться в балуне.
balloonContentHeader: 'Как сделать чтобы при клике по мне не отображался clusterBalloonItemContentLayout ?',
balloonContentBody: getContentBody(i),
balloonContentFooter: 'Мацуо Басё'
});
placemarks.push(placemark);
}
clusterer.add(placemarks);
map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);
function getRandomPosition () {
return [
mapCenter[0] + (Math.random() * 0.3 - 0.15),
mapCenter[1] + (Math.random() * 0.5 - 0.25)
];
}
var placemarkBodies;
function getContentBody (num) {
if (!placemarkBodies) {
placemarkBodies = [
['Слово скажу -', 'Леденеют губы.', 'Осенний вихрь!'].join('<br/>'),
['Вновь встают с земли', 'Опущенные дождем', 'Хризантем цветы.'].join('<br/>'),
['Ты свечу зажег.', 'Словно молнии проблеск,', 'В ладонях возник.'].join('<br/>')
];
}
return '<br>' + placemarkBodies[num % placemarkBodies.length];
}
clusterer.balloon.open(clusterer.getClusters()[0]);
});
```

Исходный код: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_balloon_carousel

Answer (score 2):

UPD: Поняла, что проблема только с балуном-панелью, там действительно не будет работать задание подмакета в null.

Можно просто полностью перезадать макет балуна кластера, пример тут https://jsfiddle.net/g8yo2vfs/

вопрос ниже неактуален 
 <s>Посмотрите пожалуйста вот этот стенд https://jsfiddle.net/qLbp62du/</s>

```
    var clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
    // Устанавливаем стандартный макет балуна кластера "Аккордеон".
    clusterBalloonContentLayout: 'cluster#balloonAccordion',
    // Устанавливаем собственный макет.
    clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: null
```

<s>Можете написать, после каких действий начинает показываться подблок?</s>

Comment: Марина, предложенный Вами метод (https://jsfiddle.net/g8yo2vfs/1/) решает проблему! Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

```
var customItemContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('');
```

Попробуй просто пустым его сделать

Comment: Такое пробовал. Пробовал на удачу и clusterBalloonItemContentLayout : false. Результат один - блок все равно открывается, но пустой. Необходимо чтобы он вообще не открывался.

Comment: clusterBalloonItemContentLayout: null тоже не срабатывает

Comment: То что ты хочешь - это уже будет не аккордеон.
Так что, думаю, надо сделать просто свой макет: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_custom_balloon_content_layout

Comment: Денис, предложенный Вами метод (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/cluster_custom_balloon_content_layout) решает проблему! В режиме clusterBalloonPanelMaxMapArea: Infinity - как раз то что нужно! Благодарю.